# Multivariate test conversion: short vs long path

Tags: usability-testing, ab-testing

Let's assume we a workflow with 3 steps.

Page 1 is our landing page.

Page 2 is the form (signup).

Page 3 is the conversion page (thank you page).

To test variations on page 1, I am running a multivariate test against several sections. 
There is a multitude of call to action buttons.

At the moment our conversion goal, is set on the thank-you page, and It means that the user clicked on the call to action, filled the form, and submitted correctly.

I feel that this approach is a bit dispersive, and doesn't tell me about the quality of the landing page.

Is it better to set the conversion on the call to action and keep the path shorter?

Comment: I'm confused here; are you asking how you should measure the results of your test or are you asking whether the short/long paths perform better?

Comment: whether short or long paths perform better..

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for A/B testing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not measuring the quality, but which option is best.
Keeping the short path will make the results more accurate if you don't have tons of users.

If you set the long path - you're measuring the connection between the form and the landing page.
Some users won't fill the form since they don't think that what you promised on page 1 is worth it.
Some won't fill it since they find out on the form that you mislead them on page 1.

So I would test ONLY the landing page, and once you get the results - move on to the next page if needed.